# Getting org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR - why?

Tags: java

Full execption stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: Si è tentato di inserire un nodo in un punto in cui non è consentito. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source)
at awtcalc2pg.parserHTML.add_component(parserHTML.java:348)
at awtcalc2pg.pDialog.create(pDialog.java:107)
at awtcalc2pg.parserHTML.parse(parserHTML.java:171)
at awtcalc2pg.parserHTML.parse(parserHTML.java:164)
at Test.main(Test.java:67)
```

My code

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;

    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fl);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i have a problem when i create a tag dialog. Because dialog have any component in him.

Test html.

```
<div>
<Dialog id="dialog"></dialog>
 </div>
```

Comment: Funny. How do you get xerces to throw exception messages in Spanish? Just for the record: did you try googling your exception name/message?

Comment: Maybe the node of an entire table being inserted in a table cell? Inserting in a child. That would explode.